# Android MediaPlayer error -1004 (ERROR_IO)

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

My application plays audio stream
Here the code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);  
mediaPlayer.prepare();  
mediaPlayer.start();
```

url is local file (127.0.0.1)
I use my own HttpServer which runs on the same phone.
After call to

```
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

I get the error:
error (1, -1004) which is ERROR_IO
Any idea what is this error?

Thanks, Costa.

Comment: are you stored music files in raw folder

Comment: Everything is OK with music files.
HTTP server gets the request and handles it good.
The problem is only with mediaPlayer.prepare(); call - it fails with the error -1004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is php5 which sends a 500 http header if your server does not send the correct headers

Answer (score 1):

Android MediaPlayer error -1004 (ERROR_IO)

You can use **mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()**, but not **mediaPlayer.prepare()**.

Please try it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with HTTP server.
I used alternative server:
http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/10/simple-http-server-java.html

And it works great!

Comment: how to use it with the following link :
[mp4 playing video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156358/why-not-all-mp4-videos-played-on-android-device/12156429#12156429)

Answer (score -2):

I change my video from mp4 to 3gp.
Its work for me.