# MediaPlayer streams MP3 in emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer

I'm using the MediaPlayer to stream MP3 files via http and it works great in the emulator, here's the heart of the code I'm using (targeting sdk version 8):

```
// play selected track      
    if(mediaplayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaplayer.reset();
    }

    try {
        mediaplayer.setDataSource(selectedTrack.url);
        mediaplayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaplayer.start();
```

However, when I try to debug it on a device (Motorola Droid RAZR running 2.3.5), I get the error below:

```
03-23 08:51:02.873: E/MediaPlayer(9442): error (1, -1004)
03-23 08:51:02.873: W/System.err(9442): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Here's the full stack trace for the run:

```
03-23 08:50:44.842: W/ActivityThread(9442): Application com.murfie.murfdroid is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-23 08:50:44.850: I/System.out(9442): Sending WAIT chunk
03-23 08:50:44.858: I/dalvikvm(9442): Debugger is active
03-23 08:50:45.045: I/System.out(9442): Debugger has connected
03-23 08:50:45.045: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:45.248: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:45.451: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:45.654: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:45.850: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:46.053: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:46.256: I/System.out(9442): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-23 08:50:46.451: I/System.out(9442): debugger has settled (1490)
03-23 08:50:46.865: D/dalvikvm(9442): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 52K, 44% free 3066K/5379K, external 2756K/2773K, paused 28ms
03-23 08:50:52.803: D/dalvikvm(9442): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 83K, 42% free 3194K/5447K, external 3453K/3470K, paused 26ms
03-23 08:50:55.912: D/dalvikvm(9442): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 21K, 42% free 3208K/5447K, external 4323K/4499K, paused 36ms
03-23 08:50:55.975: D/dalvikvm(9442): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 42% free 3205K/5447K, external 5259K/5399K, paused 25ms
03-23 08:51:02.873: E/MediaPlayer(9442): error (1, -1004)
03-23 08:51:02.873: W/System.err(9442): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
03-23 08:51:02.904: W/System.err(9442):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
03-23 08:51:02.912: W/System.err(9442):     at com.murfie.murfdroid.Murfdroid.playSelectedTrack(Murfdroid.java:162)
03-23 08:51:02.912: W/System.err(9442):     at com.murfie.murfdroid.Murfdroid.access$3(Murfdroid.java:151)
03-23 08:51:02.912: W/System.err(9442):     at com.murfie.murfdroid.Murfdroid$4.onClick(Murfdroid.java:130)
03-23 08:51:02.920: W/System.err(9442):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:932)
03-23 08:51:02.920: W/System.err(9442):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:290)
03-23 08:51:02.928: W/System.err(9442):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3602)
03-23 08:51:02.928: W/System.err(9442):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1838)
03-23 08:51:02.928: W/System.err(9442):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-23 08:51:02.936: W/System.err(9442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-23 08:51:02.936: W/System.err(9442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-23 08:51:02.936: W/System.err(9442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
03-23 08:51:02.944: W/System.err(9442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 08:51:02.944: W/System.err(9442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-23 08:51:02.944: W/System.err(9442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
03-23 08:51:02.944: W/System.err(9442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
03-23 08:51:02.951: W/System.err(9442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 08:51:02.951: E/MediaPlayer(9442): start called in state 0
03-23 08:51:02.951: E/MediaPlayer(9442): error (-38, 0)
03-23 08:51:02.975: E/MediaPlayer(9442): Error (-38,0)
```

I'm new to Android development so I may be missing something obvious here, but my guess is that it may be some sort of platform-specific issue based on other bits of info I've found googling around; if targeting a higher SDK version would change that, that may be a viable option but I'd prefer to make the app compatible with as many Android devices as possible.

Comment: All I can really help with is that 0x1 is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN which of course is not much help at all!

Comment: Yeah I wish I could get more details about why "prepare" fails; I wonder if I can get some kind of http/packet sniffer on the phone so I can monitor the conversation between the device and the web server...?

Comment: After doing some experimentation I was able to get this to work by loading the files from a web server on my development machine (as opposed to a remote server on the Internet).  I'm not sure if this has to do with security (LAN vs Internet servers), or the type of web server used (seems like I read about a problem regarding the size of the headers some servers send) so I need to do some more experiments to find the exact cause, but I'm getting closer.

Comment: This may shed some light on the subject: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution I arrived at:

After reading this thread:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17553

It became obvious that what we were trying to do would never work on pre 4.x Android and that Google had no intention of fixing it.  Given this, made two changes to my app to get it working:

1. Implemented the StreamProxy (http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/search?q=streamproxy&origq=streamproxy&btnG=Search+Trunk) approach used to make mp3 streaming compatible with pre-2.2 Android systems
2. Modified the API to use non-SSL URLs for media file sources

With these two changes the app now works on the Droid RAZR, Kindle Fire and any other piece of Android hardware I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Update -- you have "error (1, -1004)" and here's a closely related answer: [Android MediaPlayer error -1004 (ERROR_IO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211566/android-mediaplayer-error-1004-error-io)

Here's something that could possibly be relevant:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare()
"For files, it is OK to call prepare(), which blocks until MediaPlayer is ready for playback."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()
"For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered."

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Chris, this is good stuff.  I'm planning on switching to the async handler (as well as making the player a proper "service") later but for now I'm fine with blocking the main UI thread to keep things simple until it works (my one user will put up with the unresponsiveness ;)